# How do I change the placeholder like as the elements replace each other place?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do I change the placeholder like as the elements replace each other place.

Please see the example

https://jsfiddle.net/98h31o9v/11/

**JavaScript**

```
indexOfCell = 0;
```

> add boxes to #div element

```
$('#add_box').on('click', function() {
  var cell = $("<div></div>");
  var elementObj = cell.get(0);
  $('#div').append(elementObj);
  cell.addClass('content-box').attr('id', 'box_' + indexOfCell);
  cell.text(indexOfCell);
  indexOfCell += 1;
  console.log(elementObj);
  $(cell).draggable({
    helper: 'original',
    zIndex: 10001,
    start: function(event, ui) {
      if ($(this).data('placeholder') === undefined) {
        $(this).data('placeholder', createPlaceholder($(this)));
      }
      setPlaceHolder($(this).data('placeholder'), $(this));
      $(this).after($(this).data('placeholder'));
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).css('left', $(this).data('placeholder').css('left'));
      $(this).css('top', $(this).data('placeholder').css('top'));
      $(this).data('placeholder').after($(this));
      $(this).data('placeholder').detach();
    }
  });

  $(cell).droppable({
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    greedy: true,
    over: function(event, ui) {
      replaceTwoItem(ui.draggable.data('placeholder'), $(this));
    }
  });
```

> create placeholder

```
  function createPlaceholder(that) {
    var className = that.attr('class');
    var placeholder = $(document.createElement(that.get(0).nodeName))
      .addClass(className || className + " ui-sortable-placeholder")
      .removeClass("ui-sortable-helper").css({
        background: 'yellow',
        border: '1px solid grey'
      });
    return placeholder;
  }
```

> set the placeholder to cell

```
  function setPlaceHolder(placeholder, cell) {
    placeholder.css('width', cell.width());
    placeholder.css('height', cell.height());
    placeholder.css("display", 'block');
    placeholder.css('position', 'absolute');
    placeholder.css('top', cell.css('top'));
    placeholder.css('left', cell.css('left'));
  }
```

> replace two item when drag

```
  function replaceTwoItem(itemFrom, itemTo) {
    var itemToInsert;
    var action;
    if (itemFrom.index() === 0) {
      itemToInsert = itemFrom.parent();
      action = "prepend";
    } else {
      itemToInsert = itemFrom.prev();
      action = "after";
    }
    itemTo.before(itemFrom);
    if (itemTo.get(0) != itemToInsert.get(0)) {
      if (action == 'prepend') {
        itemToInsert.prepend(itemTo);
      } else if (action == 'after') {
        itemToInsert.after(itemTo);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="add_box">AddBox</button>
<div id="div">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? What exactly do you mean by "change the placeholder like as the elements replace each other place"? Do you wan't to change the colour of the moved items, or something else?

Comment: I want to change draggable item placeholder color

Comment: At the moment, only the first item has a visible placeholder. Do you want to change the yellow background of the first item?

Comment: I want to create as like here: [link](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder)

Comment: In the `createPlaceholder` method, set `background` to `none`

Comment: Not a good idea. I need to replace placeholder with drag and drop elements. any idea?

Comment: Want to do it without unordered lists.

Comment: Nice example.But want to do it with draggable and droppable, without sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the brief discussion in the comments about your requirements I think you can get rid of most of the code you're currently using. The [example](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#placeholder) on the jquery 
ui website can be tweaked slightly to get what you want.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/98h31o9v/17)

**HTML:**

```
<button id="add_box">AddBox</button>
<div id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#add_box').on('click', function() {
  //Determine the existing child count.
  var boxCount = $('#sortable').children().length;

  //Create a new "box" and add it to the end of the list.
  var newBox = $('<div class="ui-state-default">' + boxCount + '</div>');
  $('#sortable').append(newBox);

  //Invoke the sortable function to ensure the appropriate events are bound.
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  }); 
});
```

**CSS:**

The below can be cleaned up somewhat.

```
#sortable { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}

.ui-state-highlight { 
  background: yellow; 
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; 
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.ui-state-default { 
  background: green; 
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px; 
  color: black;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Update `.ui-state-default` to change the initial colour and update `.ui-state-highlight` to change the placeholder colour.